# IIS rewrite rule to remove querystring and add new folder name

Tags: php, asp.net, iis

On my website, I have a situation where 1 URL need remove query string and than add name.

So instead of looking like this: https://www.domain.com/all_job_list.php?category=1, rewrite to https://www.domain.com/all-job-list/Accounting-bookkeeping/

I've tried using below IIS/web.config rule

```
<match url="^all_job_list\.php$" />

<conditions>

    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />

    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^category=([^=&amp;]+)$" />

</conditions>

<action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

But it is not working, can any one help me for this problem.

Comment: Please go into detail about how it isn't working. What is happening? What did you expect to happen? Are there any errors in logs etc.?

Comment: No not giving any error, but not solve problem

Comment: No not giving any error, but not solve problem. I expect present url like https://www.domain.com/all_job_list.php?category=1 Rewrite https://www.domain.com/all-job-list/Accounting-bookkeeping/